# Need to create a python script to return this output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a python script to return the output like this:

Lets say input is 3.11 or 3.11.1 then output of script should be like this:

If input == 3.11 then

3.11
3.11.1
3.11.2
3.11.3
3.11.4
3.11.5
3.11.6
3.11.7
3.11.8
3.11.9
3.12
3.12.1
3.12.2
...
3.12.9
3.13

on every x.x.9 it should add one after 2nd decimal for example: after 3.12.9 it should return 3.13 and then continue the same process 3.13.1 to 3.13.9 until it reach 3.17

Here is my messy code:

```py
def get_version(version, vuln_id):
    group = version.split('.')
    max_stop = "17"
    value = []
    last = int(group[-1])
    i = -1
    # new_version =""

    if int(group[1]) == 17:
        print("ee")
        exit()
    else:
        if len(group) == 2:
            while True:
                    # get_version(n_version, "test")
                #print(i)
                i+=1
                if i == 0 :
                    new_version = str(group[0])+"."+str(group[1])+"."+str(i)

                elif i > 9:
                    new_version = str(group[0])+"."+str(int(group[1])+1)

                else:
                    new_version = str(group[0])+"."+str(int(group[1])+1)
                
                get_version(new_version, "test")
                print(new_version)
                    #get_version(n_version, "test")
        else:
            print(version)


        # new_version1 =  str(group[0])+"."+str(group[1])+"."+str(last)
        # print(new_version1)
        # for i in range(0,10):
        #     last += 1

        #     print(last)
        #     # if last > 9:
        #     #     n_version = str(group[0])+"."+str(int(group[1])+1)
        #     #     print("hehe")
        #     #     get_version(n_version, "test")
        #     new_version =  str(group[0])+"."+str(group[1])+"."+str(last)
        #     print(new_version)
```

Comment: Should be doable. Good luck. If you run into any issues, feel free to ask about them here.

Comment: You'd probably want to use loops for that, as well as the `split()` function. Have a try and ask if you need help then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat it with a prefix to handle the major version, and a float for the rest, float formatting will give the trailing (hotfix) number as you want:

```py
x = '3.11'

prefix, suffix = x.split('.', maxsplit=1)
suffix = float(suffix)
while suffix <= 17:
    print(f'{prefix}.{suffix:g}')
    suffix += 0.1
```

---